# Need help rotating instances along a curve that changes sizes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to make a square fence, and I'm having some trouble getting the instances to align properly to the correct rotation for each edge. I tried using indexing to get the correct edges isolated, but the problem is that I also want to be able to increase the size of the fence perimeter and the land its on after, which messes up the selection.

I initially used a grid for this, and got that sort of working, but I wanted to be able to resample the points by length, which lead me to the sort of janky curve set up thats there now (cube with deleted faces converted to curve).

So, any solutions for isolating an edge of a resampled square curve, while accounting for resizing? That way I can apply a rotation to just that edge?

Another kicker- I need to select one less of each edge to be able to connect the fence smoothly around the corners.

Another possible solution could be some sort of simple rotation alignment along the orientation of the curve, but I don't know how to find that or what nodes would allow me to do that.

Pretty new to geonodes so there might be an obvious solution I just don't know.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://dropover.cloud/22c5d7

Comment: https://dropover.cloud/22c5d7 ;heres the blend file

Comment: Miles, the image of your GN is unreadable.  This will hinder any expert trying to help you.

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.